# Google maps geocoding with bounds

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

With the following code when I get a result back, I don't appear to get the full address components of the result back, which we are using with our other services to determine various things.

As soon as I take the bounds out, it works fine. But I still need it restricted to the bounds.

Why is this? and how can I solve the issue?

CODE:

```
_geocoder.geocode(_.extend(position, {
                bounds: {
                    west: -25.806884999999966,
                    east: 16.380615000000034,
                    south: 48.98742739340465,
                    north: 60.16884190739975
                }
            }), function (results, status) {
                if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    _lastResults = results;

                    deferred.resolve(results);
                } else {
                    deferred.reject('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.  What is the actual call that is failing (or a least a sample of a call that fails).  Where does `_.extend` come from and what do you expect it to do?  (looks to me like you have syntax errors in the provided snippet)

Answer (score 1):

To add the bounds to the [GeocoderRequest](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#GeocoderRequest), it goes inside the request object:

```
var data = {
  bounds: {
    west: -25.806884999999966,
    east: 16.380615000000034,
    south: 48.98742739340465,
    north: 60.16884190739975
  }
};
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
               new google.maps.LatLng(data.bounds.south, data.bounds.west), 
               new google.maps.LatLng(data.bounds.north, data.bounds.east));

geocoder.geocode({
  address: "London",
  bounds: bounds
}, function(results, status) {
  if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: results[0].geometry.location,
      map: map
    });
  } else {
    alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
  }
});
```

**Note** however:

> Optional parameters:
>
> **bounds** — The LatLngBounds within which to bias geocode results more prominently. **The bounds parameter will only influence, not fully restrict, results from the geocoder**. (For more information see Viewport Biasing below.)

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gxwbL52z/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var data = {
    bounds: {
      west: -25.806884999999966,
      east: 16.380615000000034,
      south: 48.98742739340465,
      north: 60.16884190739975
    }
  };
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(new google.maps.LatLng(data.bounds.south, data.bounds.west), new google.maps.LatLng(data.bounds.north, data.bounds.east));
  var rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
    map: map,
    bounds: bounds
  });
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  geocoder.geocode({
    address: "London",
    bounds: bounds
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: results[0].geometry.location,
        map: map
      });
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: The bounds are working, that's fine, the issue is, the same search returns less within the `address_components` array when the bounds are in place, i need a full set of `address_components`

Comment: Please clarify your problem in your question.